# Who creates dependency injection object in the first place

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, dependency-injection

I would like to know who (which object) creates the real object which gets dependeny injected.

To make it more understandable here my example code

`IOrder`:

```
interface IOrder
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool SaveChanges();
}
```

`Order`:

```
public class Order : IOrder
{
    private IOrderRepository repository;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Order(IOrderRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public bool SaveChanges()
    {
        if (Id < 1)
            return repository.Save(this);
        else
            return repository.Update(this);
    }
}
```

Like we can see if i want to create an Orderobject i need to inject an some object which inherited from `IOrderRepository`

`IOrderRepository`:

```
interface IOrderRepository
{
    IList<IOrder> GetAll();
    IOrder GetById(int id);
    IList<IOrder> GetBySomeRefId(int SomeRefId);
    bool Save(IOrder order);
    bool Update(IOrder order);
}
```

`OrderRepository`:

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public IList<IOrder> GetAll()        {        }

    public IOrder GetById(int id)        {        }

    public IList<IOrder> GetBySomeRefId(int SomeRefId)        {        }

    public bool Save(IOrder order)        {        }

    public bool Update(IOrder order)        {        }
}
```

So here each `Get` method can and will inject it one class as a dependency,
but if I need a new `Order` I have to do

```
var myOrderRepos = new OrderRepository();
var myNewOrder = new Order(myorderrepos);
```

and here is my problem where ever I have to write the

```
var myOrderRepos = new OrderRepository();
```

this class will break the separation ...

And this will basically every ViewModel which has a `new` command in it in this case `NewOrderCommand`.

`OrderListVM` snipped

```
    public ICommand NewOrderCommand
    {
        get { return newOrderCommand ?? (newOrderCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OnNewOrder())); }
    }

    public void OnNewOrder()
    {
        var myOrderRepos = new OrderRepository(); // <= tight coupling to OrderRepository
        var myNewOrder = new Order(myorderrepos); // <= tight coupling to Order
        var myOrderVM = new OrderVM(myNewOrder);
        myOrderVM.Show();
    }
```

How would you avoid this tight coupling?

Comment: My first thought was "it's turtles all the way down."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec

Comment: What you are doing is applying the [Active Record Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), which should be considered an anti-pattern, because it violates [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and couples your entities to the persistence.

Comment: @Steven mmh i see, so then i should inject my `IOrderRepository` into my `OrderVM` and use the `Save()` there right?

Comment: @WiiMaxx It depends on the complexity of your application. I would even say that saving is not a responsibility of your presentation layer, but of your business layer, and probably be some infrastructural (cross-cutting concern). So my general solution is to inject the repository into a [command handler](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and inject the abstraction for that command handler into the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

Why not put a `CreateOrder` method in your `OrderRepository`? Then your view models would get an IOrderRepository injected into them and be able to create orders from there.

I wouldn't make `Order` depend on `IOrderRepository`. That seems like the wrong level to place the dependency. When you've got a repository that's doing the saving and other work, then keeping objects like Order as simple data containers and putting all the actions in the repository provides a clean separation.

I find when using dependency injection (especially when combined with repositories), my view model and controller code very rarely contains the `new` keyword.

Dependency Injection is a pattern for managing coupling. As marc_s points out in his comment, you want to depend on the abstractions, not the implementations. It's OK for your classes to have dependencies, but it's better if the interface for each dependency is given to your class than for your class to create its own version of the implementation of that dependency. That's why I don't see `new` in my classes. I know if I'm newing up an object then that's probably a good place to stop and identify how to pass that dependency into the class instead of creating it right there. Of course, a repository creating new instances of the data object it manages is a good place for a call to `new`.

Here's some code to try to help explain what I'm talking about. While working through this, I noticed you're creating `OrderVM` instances within your `OrderListVM`. So, I've taken the dependency on `IOrderRepository` out of the VMs and introduced a ViewModel factory. You may also want a `RepositoryFactory`, but that seemed like too much to show here.

`IOrder`:

```
interface IOrder
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`Order`:

```
public class Order : IOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`IOrderRepository`:

```
interface IOrderRepository
{
    IList<IOrder> GetAll();
    IOrder GetById(int id);
    IList<IOrder> GetBySomeRefId(int SomeRefId);
    bool Save(IOrder order);
    bool Update(IOrder order);
    IOrder CreateNewOrder();
}
```

`OrderRepository`:

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    ...
    public IOrder CreateNewOrder()
    {
        return new Order();
    }
}
```

`OrderListVM`:

```
public class OrderListVM 
{

    ViewModelFactory _factory;
    IEnumerable<IOrder> _orderList;

    public OrderListVM(ViewModelFactory factory, IEnumerable<IOrder> orders)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _orderList = orders;
    }

    public void OnNewOrder()
    {
        var myOrderVM = _factory.GetOrderVM();
        myOrderVM.Show();
    }
}
```

`OrderVM`

```
public class OrderVM 
{
    IOrder _order;
    public OrderVM(IOrder order)
    {
        _order = order;
    }
}
```

`ViewModelFactory`

```
interface IViewModelFactory { ... }

public class ViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory 
{
    IOrderRepository _repository;

    public ViewModelFactory (IOrderRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
    }

    public OrderListVM GetOrderListVM() {
        return new OrderListVM(this, _repository.GetAll());
    }

    public OrderVM GetOrderVM(IOrder order = null) {
        if (order == null) {
            order = _repository.CreateNewOrder();
        }
        return new OrderVM(order);
    }

}
```

Somewhere at the root of your project you'll have some bootstrap code that creates an instance of the `ViewModelFactory` and other dependencies and injects them into the classes that need them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even if i do so my `OrderListVM`will be tight coupled to the OrderRepository which will even worse than a static `Order.CreateOrder`because it would couple my DAL to my view

Comment: The snipet you included in the question has `new OrderRepository()` inside a VM, so why not inject that dependency instead of hard coding it?

Comment: to your edit, sure my it will be rare but if you client need to create a new order it has to be done somewhere in your code right? so the class contains this code will get tightly coupled to the other class

Comment: to your comment, sore i could also inject the `IOrderRepository` to my `OrderListVM` but some class will get tightly coupled to the `OrderRepository` and every other class and i would like to know how to separate this.

Comment: @WiiMaxx: you'll get a dependency on `IOrderRepository` (the **interface**) but **NOT** on `OrderRepository` (the **implementation**) - the caller could always inject another implementation of `IOrderRepository` - and that's **the whole point** - your code should rely on **abstractions** (interfaces) rather than actual implementations.

Comment: @marc_s you are right, my whole problem is where do i set the `new` ? because it has to be done some where right?

Comment: @CoderDennis maybe i'm confused or you do not understand where my problem is :( , would it be possible for you to add some sample code to explain your thoughts/ answer?

Comment: @WiiMaxx: I think you need to keep two things apart: **dependencies** like the `IOrderRepository` class, should be **injected** as a dependency, and then you don't ever need to do a `new OrderRepository();` at all. **Data classes** like the `Order` class still need to be newed up at some place - like inside the `IOrderRepository.CreateNewOrder()` method that Dennis suggested

Comment: @marc_s that's all true (even if i think the `CreateNewOrder()` should be somewhere else) , but like CoderDennis sayed "it's turtles all the way down.". The injection has to start some where with a real Object and i just want to know where i should  do that to start the injection all the way down to the places where i need them

Comment: @CoderDennis ah i see very interesting, based on your code should all my `ViewModel` implemented in this Factory ? or should i create a separate one for each (e.g. `CostumerFactory` +`ICostumerFactory`) and if i should do that wouldn't i need a FactoryFactory to get the right instance `FactoryFactory<ICostumerFactory>` for each type? which is also an anti pattern. Now i'm confused :'(

Comment: @WiiMaxx I don't know if I can be much more help here. It's hard to know what to suggest for your application. I'm not even 100% sure that I like or would use the ViewModelFactory, but it was the best way to share what I was thinking. The comment about an abstract command handler sounds like a great idea.